# ¿Cómo puedo hacer uno each dentro de un each del mismo nombre en handlebars?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, handlebars.js, handlebars

necesito un each de un each en handlebars para mi proyecto

```
{{#each daychecker}}
 <div>
  {{#each daychecker.image }}
 <h1>{{this.url}}</h1>
 {{/each}}
 </div>
 {{else}}
 <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 24rem; background: #b8974d;box-shadow: 3px 2px 10px 
 1px #0000007a;">
 <div class="card-body">
   <center>
 <h1>Bienvenido {{user.nombre}}</h1>
 <br>
    <p class="lead" style="    margin-bottom: 0px;">No hay platos disponibles aún.</p>
     <p class="lead">Nuestro horario es de lunes a viernes.</p>
 </center>
 </div>
 </div>

 {{/each}}
```

este es mi json, son los datos de mongodb y los paso a handlebars para que lo pueda leer correctamente es un return de consulta:

```
{

popularidad: 0,
adicional: [
{ nombre: 'doble proteína', precio: '3000' },
{ nombre: 'doble proteína mixta', precio: '3000' }
],
retirar_adicional: [ { nombre: 'sin salsa' }, { nombre: 'sin chips de 
papa criolla' } ],
bebidas_var: [
{ nombre: 'Limonada de coco', precio: '5000' },
{ nombre: 'Limonada de coco sin cubiertos', precio: '4500' },
{ nombre: 'limonada natural sin azúcar', precio: '4000' },
{
  nombre: 'limonada natural sin azúcar sin cubiertos',
  precio: '3500'
},
{ nombre: 'Sin bebida y sin cubiertos', precio: '0' },
{ nombre: 'Sin bebida y con cubiertos', precio: '0' }
],
image: [
{
  url:'hola',
  p_id: 'okgkprhgfl6i6sauopr1'
}
],
_id: 5da177dcbfdb2b586a0a3e03,
 nombre: 'Hamburguesa de pollo',
 descripcion: 'Hamburguesa de pollo crispy con tajada de queso y 
 tocineta 
 con salsa a base de queso y chips de papa criolla',
  precio: '12800',
diaplato: 'sábado',
createdAt: 2019-10-12T06:51:08.958Z,
updatedAt: 2019-10-12T06:51:08.958Z,
 __v: 0
 }
```

Los necesito a ambos de esta manera, si hago exactamente lo mismo, pero fuera del each padre, funciona perfectamente.

mi daychecher es un object

cualquier ayuda es agradecida :)

Answer (score 0):

Mi error fue que lo converti en formato json simplemente lo removi y use este formato en handlebars:

```
{{#each daychecker}}

<h1>{{this.nombre}}</h1>
<div>
{{#each image }}
 <h1>{{this.url}}</h1>
{{/each}}
</div>
```